# Do I need Internet to download dlc's from a disc?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

So I recently got skyrim legendary edition for the Xbox 360, but I don't have any internet on my Xbox but I was wondering if I could still download the dlcs from the disc, or do I need Internet connection?

Answer (score 6):

All the DLC is on disk, and the game is patched to 1.9. No internet is required to download the DLC. You can also choose which DLC you want to install onto your HDD.